# How to run VNC Server on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, vnc

I am trying to run VNC Server on my remote machine and installed VNC Server with the help of this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-vnc-for-ubuntu-12). I have done everything up to step 3 and am now trying step 4, but in my machine I do not get:

> /etc/init.d/vncserver

[image]

How do I run VNC Server properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 4 in that tutorial is instructing you to **create** that file (`/etc/init.d/vncserver`). This is how you will make the VNC Server as a service. The person that wrote the tutorial chose poor words, he meant to say:

> Login as root and **create** `/etc/init.d/vncserver` and add the following lines:

So, in order to complete the tutorial, just create the file and paste the text mentioned in the tutorial. To do that, you can just type in the command:

```
touch /etc/init.d/vncserver && nano /etc/init.d/vncserver
```

This will create and open the file in an editor. Copy and paste (paste by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) or type it up if you're on a desktop-less Ubuntu.

I suspect that you might also need to create the next file (`/home/vnc/.vnc/xstartup`) if doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks as i am using command prompt of ubuntu through browser any way to copy past content as i am not able to Copy-paste by CTL+V

Comment: Sorry i am doing with putty now let see now it should work

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to create startup entries

```
$ cd ~
$ > .vnc/xstartup
$ nano .vnc/xstartup
```

paste:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Create VNC Server statup script.

sudo nano /etc/init.d/vncserver

paste:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset VNCSERVERARGS
VNCSERVERS=""
[ -f /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf ] && . /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
prog=$"VNC server"
start() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
 ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1
 RETVAL=0
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 DISP="${display%%:*}"
 export VNCUSERARGS="${VNCSERVERARGS[${DISP}]}"
 su ${USER} -c "cd ~${USER} && [ -f .vnc/passwd ] && vncserver :${DISP} ${VNCUSERARGS}"
 fi
 done
}
stop() {
 . /lib/lsb/init-functions
 REQ_USER=$2
 echo -n $"Shutting down VNCServer: "
 for display in ${VNCSERVERS}
 do
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 if test -z "${REQ_USER}" -o "${REQ_USER}" == ${USER} ; then
 echo -n "${display} "
 unset BASH_ENV ENV
 export USER="${display##*:}"
 su ${USER} -c "vncserver -kill :${display%%:*}" >/dev/null 2>&1
 fi
 done
 echo -e "\n"
 echo "VNCServer Stopped"
}
case "$1" in
start)
start $@
;;
stop)
stop $@
;;
restart|reload)
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
;;
condrestart)
if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/vncserver ]; then
stop $@
sleep 3
start $@
fi
;;
status)
status Xvnc
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
exit 1
esac
```

Then

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/vncserver
sudo mkdir -p /etc/vncserver
sudo nano /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
```

vncservers.conf

```
VNCSERVERS="1:vncuser"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1024x768"
```

Bootup start entry:

```
sudo update-rc.d vncserver defaults 99
```

restart!